# Magento 2 , How to remove the loader for every page load?

Tags: magento2, frontend

After loading every page , I am getting loader and hiding . I want to remove that loader for every page , the loader html is loading after Body tag as follows

```
<div class="loading-mask" data-role="loader" style="display: none;"><div class="loader"><img alt="Loading..." src="http://local.unicorn.com/pub/static/frontend/Custom/goshop/en_US/images/loader-2.gif"><p>Please wait...</p></div></div>
```

I have checked all files and settings still unable to find from where these loader is loading. Please help me resolve this.

Answer (score 2):

You can remove it using CSS

```
.loading-mask {
    display: none;
}
```